# MySQL table not creating error #1064

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1064

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE companyprinciple {
userid INT, 
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
}ENGINE=INNODB;
```

and here is the error that I am getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{
userid INT, 
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
}ENG' at line 1
```

unfortunately most of my experience in db programming is in postgreSQL, and the foreign keys work a lot better there it seems.

EDIT: alright so the first problem was that my eyes were closed and the { } should be ( ) but now i am getting a new error

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'ourhoursdb.companyprinciple' (errno: 150)
```

here is the full ddl.sql (... is other columns, this table is creating fine though)

```
CREATE SCHEMA OurHoursDB;
USE OurHoursDB;

CREATE TABLE User (
id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
...

) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE companyprinciple (
userid INT, 
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: According to the manuel there are no "{" to write (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use round parenthesis pair `()`. **NOT** the curly ones `{}`.

Also make sure you have created `user` table with an `id` column with **exact same type** first.

Comment: well you were right but now i get this, #1005 - Can't create table 'ourhoursdb.companyprinciple' (errno: 150)

Comment: Check my answer again. Did you create user table first?

Comment: alright i got it, i was using SERIAL and INT which it didnt like

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE companyprinciple (
  userid INT, 
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: @CraigDykstra: You have no user table with id column.

Comment: ill add my full ddl.sql to the question